# Can you match or search with cell matching part of another?

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to create a formula in Excel where I can use an Index / Match formula where I'm searching for only part of one cell.

For example:

**Sheet 1**

Column A --> Full Name

Column B --> Removed status

|  | Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D | Col E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Col D + Col E | Removed status | agent # | Agent F Name | Agent L Name |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |  |

**Sheet 2**

Column A --> Sheet 1 Column B --> only if Sheet 1 Column A is part of Sheet 2 Column D

Column D --> Full Name 1, Full Name 2, Full Name 3

|  | Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D | Col E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sheet 1 Col B | AutoP status | Carged | Name 1, Name 2, Name 3 | Notes |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |  |

So, I'm hoping to get a formula to display Sheet 1 Column B into Sheet 2 Column A only if Sheet 1 Column A can be found as part of Sheet 2 Column D.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search for part of one cell, you can use `find` formula which search for given text within cell value `find(text,withintext)` and it return index that the text start with and error if not.

And if you need your process to be work line by line,
the final formula ( for row2 of sheet2 column A ) would look like this:

`=IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(FIND(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!D2))),Sheet1!A2<>""),Sheet1!A2,"")`

if row2 of column A of sheet1 is not empty and is found (no error returned);the value of sheet1 column A returned otherwise empty will returned.

Hope that was useful.